# Capture keys in SWT text

Tags: java, swt, keyup

I have some problems to detect the keys pressed in a text field.

That's my text class and then I have also two buttons:

```
text1 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.NO_SCROLL | SWT.SINGLE);
text1.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent(Event e) {
    e.doit = false;
    int i = e.stateMask + e.keyCode;
    text1.setText(Integer.toString(i));
  }
});

okayButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
okayButton.setText("&OK");

cancelButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
cancelButton.setText("&Abbrechen");
```

My problem is that global keys seem to be handled before my own handler.
For example if I press Alt+O then the OK button is triggered but not my handler. The same effect by pressing escape.

How can I prevent executing global shortcuts and only executing my own handleEvent method?

Comment: What 'global keys'? Is this a standalone SWT application?

Comment: With 'global keys', the OP refers to the mnemonics used to focus/trigger the '&OK' button.

Comment: Why would you want to _override_ the mnemonics or the Esc key?

Comment: It is not forceful necessary to capture the escape key. It was only an example for the global event triggering. It concerns ESC, RETURN, Alt+O, Alt+A, Ctrl+P and some more. And that's not satisfiable.